# How to highlight first occurrence of a string in a UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I use the javascript code below to find all occurrences of a string in UIWebView:

UIWebViewSearch.js:

```
var uiWebview_SearchResultCount = 0;

/*!
 @method     uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement
 @abstract   // helper function, recursively searches in elements and their child nodes
 @discussion // helper function, recursively searches in elements and their child nodes

 element    - HTML elements
 keyword    - string to search
 */

function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element,keyword) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 3) {        // Text node

            var count = 0;
            var elementTmp = element;
            while (true) {
                var value = elementTmp.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
                var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

                if (idx < 0) break;

                count++;
                elementTmp = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
            }

            uiWebview_SearchResultCount += count;

            var index = uiWebview_SearchResultCount;
            while (true) {
                var value = element.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
                var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

                if (idx < 0) break;             // not found, abort

                //we create a SPAN element for every parts of matched keywords
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx,keyword.length));
                span.appendChild(text);

                span.setAttribute("class","uiWebviewHighlight");
                span.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
                span.style.color="black";

                index--;
                span.setAttribute("id", "SEARCH WORD"+(index));
                //span.setAttribute("id", "SEARCH WORD"+uiWebview_SearchResultCount);

                //element.parentNode.setAttribute("id", "SEARCH WORD"+uiWebview_SearchResultCount);

                //uiWebview_SearchResultCount++;    // update the counter

                text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
                element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);

                var next = element.nextSibling;
                //alert(element.parentNode);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
                element = text;
            }


        } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
            if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
                for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i],keyword);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// the main entry point to start the search
function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(keyword) {
    uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights();
    uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(document.body, keyword.toLowerCase());
}

// helper function, recursively removes the highlights in elements and their childs
function uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 1) {
            if (element.getAttribute("class") == "uiWebviewHighlight") {
                var text = element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text,element);
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                return true;
            } else {
                var normalize = false;
                for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    if (uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element.childNodes[i])) {
                        normalize = true;
                    }
                }
                if (normalize) {
                    element.normalize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// the main entry point to remove the highlights
function uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights() {
    uiWebview_SearchResultCount = 0;
    uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(document.body);
}

function uiWebview_ScrollTo(idx) {
    var scrollTo = document.getElementById("SEARCH WORD" + idx);
    if (scrollTo) scrollTo.scrollIntoView();
}
```

And in my ViewController.swift file, I load the javascript file and perform a search like so:

```
func highlightAllOccurencesOfString(str:String) -> Int {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "UIWebViewSearch", ofType: "js")

        var jsCode = ""

        do{

            jsCode = try String(contentsOfFile: path!)

               myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: jsCode)

        let startSearch = "uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('\(str)')"

        myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: startSearch)

        let result = myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "uiWebview_SearchResultCount")!

        }catch
        {
            // do something

        }



        return  Int(result)!


    }
```

This finds and highlights all occurrences of a string within the webview, but I only want the first occurrence highlighted.
For example, with this code when I call:

```
highlightAllOccurencesOfString(str:"Hello")
```

All instances of "Hello" gets highlighted in the webview:

`Hello` Frank, `Hello` Noah

But I want this result:

`Hello` Frank, Hello Noah

How do I modify the javascript code to highlight only the first occurrence of a searched string?

**UPDATE:** I tried JonLuca's answer below but nothing got highlighted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The function is operating like a tree, where it checks if the element is a text node, and if not it calls itself on every one of its children.

You have to let the caller know that you found a single element to highlight, and then leave.

Also, the way this searches through it does not guarantee that what you consider is the "first" occurrence of the word will be the first occurence within the document.body tree.

Within the code, have it return true if it found a word to highlight, and false otherwise. That'll prevent it from continuing its search. Modify the js like so:

```
function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element, keyword) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 3) { // Text node

            var count = 0;
            var elementTmp = element;

            var value = elementTmp.nodeValue; // Search for keyword in text node
            var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

            if (idx < 0) {
                return false;
            }

            count++;
            elementTmp = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx + keyword.length));


            uiWebview_SearchResultCount += count;

            var index = uiWebview_SearchResultCount;

            var value = element.nodeValue; // Search for keyword in text node
            var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

            if (idx < 0) {
                return false;
            } // not found, abort

            //we create a SPAN element for every parts of matched keywords
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx, keyword.length));
            span.appendChild(text);

            span.setAttribute("class", "uiWebviewHighlight");
            span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            span.style.color = "black";

            index--;
            span.setAttribute("id", "SEARCH WORD" + (index));
            //span.setAttribute("id", "SEARCH WORD"+uiWebview_SearchResultCount);

            //element.parentNode.setAttribute("id", "SEARCH WORD"+uiWebview_SearchResultCount);

            //uiWebview_SearchResultCount++;    // update the counter

            text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx + keyword.length));
            element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);

            var next = element.nextSibling;
            //alert(element.parentNode);
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
            element = text;
            return true;


        } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
            if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
                for (var i = element.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i], keyword)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't guaranteed to be correct, or that it covers all of your use cases. However, I had it return true on the first occurrence of finding the highlighted word. It should stop executing and not highlight any other words.

Let me know if this works or not - I don't have the ability to test it right now.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, your code didn't work. Nothing gets highlighted :(  Can you test it now?

Comment: @JonLuca, I'm also looking for a solution. I tried your code but it didn't work. Can you suggest any other solution?